# Do radiowaves lose energy when reflected? Do they lose penetratio power?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, radio-frequency

Radio waves can penetrate walls.
When they are reflected by conductors do they lose that "penetration power"?

Comment: Related question by the same member: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273023/

Answer (score 1):

Reflection of RF is a result of currents flowing in the surface that is doing the reflecting. Most surfaces are not perfect conductors, and so there will be energy dissipated by these currents.

That, in turn, means that the reflected wave will have less power than the incident wave.

"Penetrating power" can be thought of as meaning one of two things: one, the fraction of energy that penetrates a certain depth. That fraction is a function of the frequency, but not the power, of the incident wave. Therefore, that fraction will only change if the object that is doing the reflecting is moving relative to the source (so the reflection will be Doppler shifted).

But if by "penetrating power" you mean the energy that makes it through a certain thickness of wall, then yes - the fact that the wave reflected before, and that is has therefore already lost some power, will mean that less power makes it through the next obstacle.

I hope the above way of thinking about this problem helps you figure out the specifics for the problem you are actually thinking about.

Comment: I have flagged this user for possible moderater intervention,  as there is a pattern of (at least 6),  variations of the same simple two line question.